# How to add a class to a postLink form - CakePHP 3.4

Tags: forms, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.4

Is it possible to add a class to the hidden form created by CakePHP's postLink form helper?

Here's my code

```
    Form->postLink(
        ' ' . __('Delete'),
        ['action' => 'delete', $this->fetch('item')],
        ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $this->fetch('item'))
        ,'escape' => false
        ,'title' => __('Delete')
        ,'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs isAction'
        ]) ?>
```

Note that I'm not looking to add a class to the link that gets created.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: It is possible, not overly straightforward though... why do you need to do that in the first place? Maybe there's a better way to do whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to catch the form submission with JS client-side based on a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's pretty much only one way currently, and that would be to change the `formStart` template temporarily, something along the lines of this:

```
// read current template and set the new one
$formStart = $this->Form->getTemplates('formStart');
$this->Form->setTemplates([
    'formStart' => '<form class="hiddenFormClass"{{attrs}}>'
]);

echo $this->Form->postLink(/* ... */);

// set the template back to its previous state
$this->Form->setTemplates([
    'formStart' => $formStart
]);
```

It's also possible to reset the templates to their default state using the `resetTemplates()` method, however this would reset all possible changes made to any of the templates, so it's probably better to play it safe as shown above.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Views > Helpers > Form > Customizing the Templates FormHelper Uses](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses)**
- **[API \Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper::setTemplates()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#_setTemplates)**
- **[API \Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper::getTemplates()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#_getTemplates)**
- **[API \Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper::resetTemplates()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#_resetTemplates)**

Comment: Works perfectly. Thx for the insight.